# What should our FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

Coming from Programmers where we've had entire wars over site scope and the FAQ, I think it'd be good to get this hammered out as soon as possible. So what should the FAQ contain?

Comment: This is definitely a good thing to settle as soon as possible. However, given that this beta has been live for less than half an hour, I don't think we've seen enough questions to get a feel for what works, what doesn't, and what should be clarified. In other words, I don't think there's enough information yet to answer this question well.

Comment: Oh, I'm well aware of that, I just like getting things nailed out early...really, really early.

Comment: Oh, I agree. One of the first things we settled on Christianity.SE (where I'm a mod) was the site's definition of "Christian".

Comment: Perhaps it makes more sense to think about the FAQ after some period of time, repeat questions or questions with a lot of votes will start to emerge and from that list you will get meta questions that tend to be a combination of a few more common questions - those are the kinds of Questions that FAQ are great for.  But also we'll want to see a few 'First Principle' topics that help shape how someone might think about asking questions and finding solutionsm, like: "do i really need to ask this question or should I google it first for 10 minutes"

Comment: I suppose we could start off with the most obvious ones, which might not actually be frequently asked questions, but still questions that are good to have in a FAQ. Such as "What is Blender".

Answer (score 2):

Wait a few months, see what questions people ask frequently, and there's the answer to your question.

Some websites have fabricated FAQ pages.  They guess at things visitors might want to know, and write questions and answers.  Maybe the information is accurate and useful, but the FAQ concept is treated a writing format. The worst-offending sites don't even have a good description of what they're all about, who runs it, what they offer - it's all shoveled into the fake FAQ.  "Frequently Asked Questions" ceases to mean much.

We shouldn't do that.